# How to create a bridging header in a react native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bridging-header

I am trying to integrate my react native iOS application with a third-party analytics tool and the integration process has a step of creating a bridging header in Xcode and including the import in that header.

[image]

The link in this image redirects me to the Apple documentation which provides the steps to create a bridging header.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-objective-c-into-swift

I followed the exact steps which are:  File > New > File > [operating system] > Source > Header File (you can see the attached screenshot below).

[image]

But I dont see any swift compiler or a path to the bridging header file in the build settings. What do I need to do to successfully create the bridging header and import the package?